# Why does json.dumps() throw a 500 internal server error when using variables?

Tags: jquery, python, django, json

I've tested this out thoroughly and I have no idea why it's doing this, so I was wondering if someone could explain...

json.dumps() is throwing a 500 internal server error when I try to use a variable instead of a string.

For example:

```
error = 'Login Failed:  Your username or password is incorrect.'
test = json.dumps({'form': error})
```

will return a 500 internal server error when attempting to return through jQuery.ajax

However,

```
test = json.dumps({'form': 'Login Failed:  Your username or password is incorrect.'})
```

will not throw a 500 internal server error.  I've tested this out thoroughly with single quotes, double quotes, different formatting, etc and it all points to json.dumps()

For some reason, this is only occurring when calling the view through jQuery.ajax

even if i don't return json.dump() and return a normal json object it still throws  a 500 error, which is why I've concluded that it's json.dumps() and not the .ajax call **

Here's an extra snippet of code where I'm using this:  For unknown reasons.. this will throw an error while calling this particular page through jQuery.ajax()

Yes.. even though the variable 'test' is not being returned.

```
        elif(password == 'testing_this'):
             error = 'Login Failed:  Your username or password is incorrect.'
             errors = True

        test = json.dumps({'form': error})
        #print test
        date = datetime.date.today()

        if(errors == True):
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'form': 'error message here'}), mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': True}), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Hey, if you look at the 500 error in the Firebug console and click the "HTML" tab, it will show you the Django output, and then you can get the specific error.

Comment: idk if i'm missing something.. but the "inspect element" feature on chrome isn't showing anything and here's a link to the firebug output.. http://snapplr.com/k1me

P.S. i changed 'testing_this' to '1234567' in my screenshot example

Comment: Don't think Chrome can do it. In the "Console" tab it shows AJAX requests, and if you click the `+` beside the request there will be a "HTML" tab there which shows you the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning DEBUG on in settings, and going through traceback may be useful.

Just of the wall, i may assume that before this check (if(errors == True):) You may forgot to initialize errors with initial value so it throws NameError... But it's just an assumption.

UPD: Sorry ajax part slipped my mind - +1 to [waitinforatrain's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281469/waitinforatrain) comment

Comment: yeah.. the error's behind the scenes so debug doesn't come up.. pasted firebug stuff in a comment.  only thing i notice is "dataset undefined {}" but I'm not sure if that's from the ajax call or not

Comment: It's not HTML you want to inspect - try Network tab > select request > Content Tab - there must be source of Django debug page.

Comment: wow.. i fk'd up bad on this one...  i was getting a 500 because error was never being set.  my if statement was catching it.  I figured something else was messed up.. that just seemed way too weird.

Comment: you were partially correct with the "errors", except it was error that wasn't being referenced.. so i'll give you the question. :p